# Overloading std::string constructor

Tags: c++, constructor-overloading

Can I overload the std::string constructor?

I want to create a constructor which takes std::wstring and return a std::string. is it possible and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Inheriting from std::string is inadvisable. It does not have a virtual destructor and will cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I overload the std::string constructor?

Nope, it would require changing `std::string` declaration.

> I want to create a constructor which takes std::wstring and return a std::string. is it possible and how?

You can have a conversion function instead, like:

```
std::string to_string(std::wstring const& src);
```

However, you need to decide what to do with symbols that can't be represented using 8-bit encoding of `std::string`: whether to convert them to multi-byte symbols or throw an exception. See [wcsrtombs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs) function.

Comment: The conversion option did come in mind. but the compiler wouldn't auto-use it in function calls. instead of me calling the conversion each time.

Comment: Right. you can have a very short name for that function though. Like `std::string operator~(std::wstring const&)`.

Comment: @Maxim: That's not a good suggestion. `operator~` is not "conversion" by intuition.

Comment: Well... I guess I have to go over all my code and convert it manually ):

Comment: @Maxim: Good is when your operator/function-name is intuitive or has a counterpart in maths (e.g. `operator+` makes sense for vectors/matrices). Some of the C++ standard literature handles this topic. See also [GotW 97](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice97.htm). Overloading `operator~`, which is bitwise not, has nothing to do with conversion; you do it for the cuteness only, without any deeper thinking, i.e. for sake of itself.

Comment: Not-wide-string is intuitive enough for me: means I don't want a wide string, rather I want a narrow string. But again, what is intuitive for me may be not so intuitive for you, it is in the eye of the beholder. And I prefer cute code over ugly one.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: `float` is not a `wstring`, `basic_string<long long>` is not a `wstring`, StackOverflow is not a `wstring`. Mistaking bitwise not (`operator~`) with logical not (`operator!`). All this confusion, no clear solution. It works for you _now_, but will you remember your malefactions for eternity? My hope is no innocent programmer ever has to maintain and/or debug your code. If at all, you should be declared the sole maintainer of your code so as to do penance for spreading this mis-wisdom that looks neat but gains naught.

Comment: Nice rant, but you forget to add "in my opinion". Because this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Maxim: I understand that this is your opinion, the problem being that StackOverflow is a community from/for professional and serious amateur programmers. By proposing neat code you make us the maintainers of your mind. Maybe you understand better if you let me give you some syntactically valid fantasy code of a fantasy OpenGL wrapper: `auto image = ++_<X|Y>()>--^~-W->*P;`. That's really neat. But would you want to maintain it for a living? (again: I understand opinion, but SO endeavors good practice if not stated explicitly otherwise).

Comment: By "in my opinion" i meant your opinion, hence the quotes. Anyway, that OpenGL wrapper might find its audience amongst Perl programmers. I wouldn't like it but would not be ranting about it, there is plenty of choice...

Comment: @Maxim: My fail. However, I just talked about common practice, which happens to fit my own opinion. You can find this also in e.g. Sutter's and Meyers' C++ literature. To find a consensus: I like neat code, too (see http://gitorious.org/metatrace), but not for production, and you won't find me recommending such compile time insanity on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Rather define a free function:

```
std::string func(const std::wstring &)
{
}
```

Comment: That is not possible in C++ (if you meant this to be a conversion operator, which must be a member, if you mean this to be something else, then I don't have an idea what you mean it should be)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: you're right and you should have downvoted. Changed to free function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add any new constructors to `std::string`. What you *can* do is create a standalone conversion function:

```
std::string wstring_to_string(const wstring& input)
{
    // Your logic to throw away data here.
}
```

If you (think you) want this to happen automatically, I strongly suggest re-evaluating that idea. You'll cause yourself a significant amount of headaches as `wstring`s are automatically treated as `string` when you least expect it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Right True Way of doing it, and I think that I had smoked something when I coded this, but it solves the problem. Check the last function, `convert_str'.

```
#pragma once    

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_const.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/logical.hpp>

template <typename Target, typename Source, typename cond>
struct uni_convert {
};

template <typename Target, typename Source > 
struct uni_convert<Target,Source,
    typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_same<Target, Source>, int >::type > {
    static Target doit(Source const& src) 
    {

        return src;
    }
};

template <typename Cond > 
struct uni_convert<std::string,std::wstring,
    Cond > {
    static std::string doit(std::wstring const& src) 
    {
        std::vector<char> space(src.size()*2, 0);
        wcstombs( &(*( space.begin() )), src.c_str(), src.size()*2 );
        std::string result( &(*( space.begin() )) );
        return result;
    }
};

template <typename Cond > 
struct uni_convert<std::wstring,std::string,
    Cond > {
    static std::wstring doit(std::string const& src) 
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> space(src.size()*2, 0);
        mbstowcs( &(*( space.begin() )), src.c_str(), src.size()*2 );
        std::wstring result( &(*( space.begin() )) );
        return result;
    }
};

template< typename TargetChar >
std::basic_string< TargetChar > convert_str( std::string const& arg)
{
    typedef std::basic_string< TargetChar > result_t;
    typedef uni_convert< result_t, std::string, int > convertor_t;
    return convertor_t::doit( arg );
}
```

Comment: How is this better than `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(wstring)`?

Comment: Ahh, that's the Right True Way. I didn't know ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to smoke some more (-`

Comment: Well, I'm glad that boost::lexical_cast is the Right True Way. And I hope that it can be used again soon. Right now, boost 1.48 + gcc4.6 with c++11 = some-rvalue-binding-that-can-not be done.